# Test class for Scheduled Batch class making a callout in the start method

Tags: unit-test, callout, schedulebatch, httpcalloutmock, scheduled-job

I have two classes - BatchClass and SchedulerClass. Batch class makes an API callout in the start method and return the list of records to insert. This class is scheduled with the help of SchedulerClass. I'm new to Apex coding and had to put a lot of efforts to make this work. Now, it's working and inserting records perfectly but I'm not sure how do I write a test class for this. I would be really glad if someone could help me out!

Thanks in advance :)

Here are my classes:

```
global class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<Report__c>, Database.AllowsCallouts 
{

global List<Report__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

    //web service callout here where response is json

    // convert json to list

    return list;

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<HackeroneReport__c> scope)
{
    upsert list;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{     
} 

}




global class SchedulerClass implements Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts
{

public static String sched = '0 15 15 * * ?'; 

    global static String scheduleReportBatch() 
    {
    SchedulerClass SC = new SchedulerClass(); 
    return System.schedule('Insert Reports batch Job', sched, SC);
    }    


    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {

    BatchClass b = new BatchClass();
    ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b,15);          
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set a Mock response for your callout. Use `Test.setMock()` method to return your mock response.

Refer to documentation [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm) for the usage of `Test.setMock()`.

While this is great if your callout is being done in a separate method and you can test it directly, in your batch class you may want to use

```
Map<String, Object> calloutData = ( Test.isRunningTest() ? TestRunner.getMockData() : BatchJob.getData() );
```

Where the above code would call a method to return some Mock Data that can be used in your test class, and the other would be however you would normally be getting your callout data in your

`global Iterable<Object> start( Database.BatchableContext BC ){}`

method. Note the method calls for your callouts are completely generic as you will need to do this part yourself. The documentation I provided should help a lot in being able to generate your sample callout data. You can also develop a method that would return a JSON String that you can parse into  a map to make it easier to work with (assuming that is the form that you are using to build your insert object(s) )

Answer (score 0):

You can call batch class using following logic:

```
Test.startTest();
       BatchClass  b = new BatchClass ();
       database.executebatch(b);    
Test.stopTest();
```

But for that you have to create a test data.

For schedule class you can use following logic

```
Test.startTest();
    SchedulerClass shInstance= new SchedulerClass ();
     String sch = '0 0 4 ? * * *';        
    string cronId=system.schedule('Testing Schedule', sch, shInstance);
    CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                      FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :cronID];
    System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
    Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: your testmethod for the scheduler class is not best practice as you want to test that the batchable class was scheduled for execution; testing that a cronTrigger was created tells you nothing as System.schedule by definition will do this